# iOS change accessibility focus

Tags: ios, iphone, ios4, accessibility, uiaccessibility-notification

Is there a way to set the accessibility focus programatically (App Store safe)? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think this is the same as my http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7509748/initial-voiceover-selection

Comment: Does David’s earlier question answer your question?

Answer (score 71):

To focus on element you can call.

Swift:

```
UIAccessibility.post(notification: .screenChanged, argument: self.myFirstView)
```

ObjC:

```
UIAccessibilityPostNotification(UIAccessibilityScreenChangedNotification, self.myFirstView);
```

Otherwise for iOS 8+ use the accessibilityElements to set element order and it will focus automatically on first element in the list

```
self.accessibilityElements = @[myFirstView, mySecondButton, myThirdLabel]
```

Comment: There is also `UIAccessibilityLayoutChangedNotification` if the screen didn't change but some view appeared/disappeared in the current screen

Answer (score 12):

```
extension UIAccessibility {
    static func setFocusTo(_ object: Any?) {
        if UIAccessibility.isVoiceOverRunning {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.8) {
                UIAccessibility.post(notification: .layoutChanged, argument: object)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Add this extension and call it by passing in the view you would like to be focused. If you would like to change focus when navigating using a tabbar, you can call this from viewWillAppear. This code wont work in any init method without a the delay of 0.7 or more.

Answer (score 2):

This is the Swift code:

```
UIAccessibility.post(notification: .screenChanged, argument: <theView>)
```

Example usage

```
let titleLabel = UILabel()

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        UIAccessibility.post(notification: .screenChanged, argument: titleLabel)
}
```

Comment: I found this often causes the default UIView to be read first and then that gets interrupted with this titleLabel being read.  Tried in viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear but that got ignored.  Any workarounds for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
UIAccessibility.post(notification: .layoutChanged, argument: toast)
toast.becomeFirstResponder()
toast.isAccessibilityElement = true
toast.accessibilityTraits = .staticText //Traits option ie .header, .button etc
toast.accessibilityLabel = "Accessibility label to be read by VoiceOver goes here"
```

WHERE:

- `toast` is my UIView (a pop up which gets triggered upon particular scenario)
- above code needs to be added to the toast `View`
- this code will automatically change focus to pop up view (`toast`) and VoiceOver will read `accessibilityLabel`