# Change order of read items with VoiceOver

Tags: ios, accessibility, voiceover

I have a bunch of buttons on the screen which are positioned intuitively visually but are not read in an intuitive order by VoiceOver. This is because certain buttons like Up and Down are placed above and below each other. However, voiceover starts reading from Left to Right, from Top to Bottom, it seems.

This results in voiceover reading the button to the right of "Up" after "Up", instead of reading "Down" immediately afterward.

How do I force voiceover to read the button that I want to read? I should mention that I'm using the swipe-to-cycle-through-elements feature on voiceover.

All my buttons are subclassed versions of UIView and UIButton. Here's an example of a button initiator I use. Ignore the pixel count - I know that's bad form but I'm in a pinch at the moment:

```
UIButton* createSpecialButton(CGRect frame, 
                                 NSString* imageName, 
                                 NSString* activeImageName,
                                 id target,
                                 SEL obClickHandler) 
{
    UIButton* b = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [b setImage:[GlobalHelper nonCachedImage:imageName ofType:@"png"] 
       forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [b setImage:[GlobalHelper nonCachedImage:activeImageName ofType:@"png"] 
       forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [b addTarget:target action:obClickHandler forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];    
    b.frame= frame;
    return b;
}


- (UIButton *) createSendButton {
    CGFloat yMarker = 295;

    UIButton* b = createSpecialButton(CGRectMake(160, yMarker, 70, 45),
                                          @"Share_Btn",
                                          @"Share_Selected_Btn",
                                          self,
                                          @selector(sendAction));
    b.accessibilityHint = @"Send it!";
    b.accessibilityLabel = @"Stuff for voiceover to be added";
    [self.view addSubview:b];

    return b;
}
```

Comment: Adding some code would help.

Comment: Would it? Because I basically just have a bunch of functions that init buttons and add them to the mainview as subviews. They're made to be accessible and have accessibility hints and labels. What do you need to know about the code?

Comment: It would help in terms of how and the order you init the buttons

Comment: I added some code. This is how I add several of my buttons. I call createSpecialButton, get it returned and add it to the view.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The easiest answer to this lies in creating a `UIView` subclass that contains your buttons, and responds differently to the accessibility calls from the system. These important calls are:

```
-(NSInteger)accessibilityElementCount
-(id)accessibilityElementAtIndex:
-(NSInteger)indexOfAccessibilityElement:
```

I've seen a few of these questions, and [answered one before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13133633/927947), but I've not seen a generic example of how to reorder the VoiceOver focus. So here is an example of how to create a `UIView` subclass that exposes its accessible subviews to VoiceOver by tag.

**AccessibilitySubviewsOrderedByTag.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface AccessibilitySubviewsOrderedByTag : UIView
@end
```

**AccessibilitySubviewsOrderedByTag.m**

```
#import "AccessibilityDirectional.h"
@implementation AccessibilitySubviewsOrderedByTag {
    NSMutableArray *_accessibilityElements;
}
    //Lazy loading accessor, avoids instantiating in initWithCoder, initWithFrame, or init.
-(NSMutableArray *)accessibilityElements{
    if (!_accessibilityElements){
        _accessibilityElements = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return _accessibilityElements;
}
// Required accessibility methods...
-(BOOL)isAccessibilityElement{
    return NO;
}
-(NSInteger)accessibilityElementCount{
    return [self accessibilityElements].count;
}
-(id)accessibilityElementAtIndex:(NSInteger)index{
    return [[self accessibilityElements] objectAtIndex:index];
}
-(NSInteger)indexOfAccessibilityElement:(id)element{
    return [[self accessibilityElements] indexOfObject:element];
}
// Handle added and removed subviews...
-(void)didAddSubview:(UIView *)subview{
    [super didAddSubview:subview];
    if ([subview isAccessibilityElement]){
        // if the new subview is an accessibility element add it to the array and then sort the array.
        NSMutableArray *accessibilityElements = [self accessibilityElements];
        [accessibilityElements addObject:subview];
        [accessibilityElements sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2){
            // Here we'll sort using the tag, but really any sort is possible.
            NSInteger one = [(UIView *)obj1 tag];
            NSInteger two = [(UIView *)obj2 tag];
            if (one < two) return NSOrderedAscending;
            if (one > two) return NSOrderedDescending;
            return NSOrderedSame;
        }];
    }
}
-(void)willRemoveSubview:(UIView *)subview{
    [super willRemoveSubview:subview];
    // Clean up the array. No check since removeObject: is a safe call.
    [[self accessibilityElements] removeObject:subview];
}
@end
```

Now simply enclose your buttons in an instance of this view, and set the tag property on your buttons to be essentially the focus order.

Comment: I wonder if this still works in iOS 7? I've put in all these methods, and they're just never called by iOS no matter what I do, so they have no effect on anything.

Comment: @MusiGenesis I just tested the project that this code is from on an iPad mini Retina running 7.1 from Xcode 5.1.1 and it ran as expected. These methods won't be called unless VoiceOver is on. Also, they may be obstructed by views closer to the root view. Can't really help much without more information, except to say that they do still work.

Comment: Is there any protocol that specifies which all methods need to be implemented ? Can you specify any links to apple docs that might be helpful ?

Comment: Oh, nifty approach using tags.

Alas, I often use tags for other purposes (such as doing radio button groups), but this might help.

Answer (score 58):

You can change the order by setting the view's [accessibilityElements](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1615147-accessibilityelements) array:

```
self.view.accessibilityElements = @[self.view1, self.view2, self.view3, self.view4];
```

or

```
self.anotherView.accessibilityElements = @[self.label1, self.txtView1, self.label2, self.txtView2];
```

If you need to enable user interaction programmatically:

```
[self.view1 setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```

**Note:** If the view is hidden, VoiceOver will not pass through it.

Comment: this does not work for my application...I did try to make sure all the views are not hidden.

Answer (score 16):

In Swift you just have to set view's [accessiblityElements](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1615147-accessibilityelements) array property:

```swift
view.accessibilityElements = [view1, view2, view3] // order you wish to have
```

Comment: Swift is just a programming language. This technique works in Objective-C as well, but it can be a pain when you don’t have outlets for every view.

Comment: In objective-c, in this case, just add an `@` before the literal array 
`view.accessibilityElements = @[view1, view2, view3]`

Answer (score 7):

I know this is an old thread, but I found that the easiest way to do it is to subclass `UIView`. Then simply modify your main `UIView` type in storyboard to `AccessibiltySubviewsOrderedByTag` and update the tags in each subview you want to read in order.

```swift
class AccessibilitySubviewsOrderedByTag: UIView {
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        
        self.accessibilityElements = [UIView]()
        for accessibilitySubview in self.subviews {
            if accessibilitySubview.isAccessibilityElement {
                self.accessibilityElements?.append(accessibilitySubview)
            }
        }
        self.accessibilityElements?.sort(by: {($0 as AnyObject).tag < ($1 as AnyObject).tag})
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This doesn’t directly answer the original question, but it answers the title of the question:

When I want VoiceOver to swipe down a column, I have been using a containing view for the column with `shouldGroupAccessibilityChildren` set.

I wish I had known this earlier, because it can be a pain to retroactively insert containers into an autolayout situation…

Answer (score 3):

I tried [Wesley's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31548554/156210) of setting the array of the `accessibilityElements` but it didn't work for me.

Apple has some documentation [Enhancing the Accessibility of Table View Cells](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW5) with an example in code. Basically you set the accessibility label of the cell (the parent view) to the values of the accessibility labels of the child views.

```
[cell setAccessibilityLabel:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@", cityLabel, temperatureLabel]];
```

This is what worked for me.

Comment: Don't forget to set the parent view's `isAccessibilityElement` property to true.

Answer (score 2):

I found a convenience way yesterday. Similar to @TejAces ' answer.
Make a new swift file, then copy these things into it.

```
import UIKit

extension UIView {
    func updateOrder(_ direction: Bool = true) {
        var tempElements: [Any]? = [Any]()
        let views = (direction) ? subviews : subviews.reversed()
        for aView in views {
            tempElements?.append(aView)
        }
        accessibilityElements = tempElements
    }
}

class ReorderAccessibilityByStoryBoardView: UIView {
    override func didAddSubview(_ subview: UIView) {
        updateOrder()
        super.didAddSubview(subview)
    }
}
```

Set the UIView(contains views you want to reorder)'s class as ReorderAccessibilityByStoryBoardView. Then you can reorder them by reordering storyboard's view list.

[image: view list]

Because subview doesn't contain views in StackView/ScrollView, you need to make a independent class in this file. Such as the ReorderAccessibilityByStoryBoardStackView down below.

```
class ReorderAccessibilityByStoryBoardStackView: UIStackView {
    override func didAddSubview(_ subview: UIView) {
        updateOrder(false)
        super.didAddSubview(subview)
    }
}
```

With these codes, you can also reorder view's added in code by adding them in a specific order.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do it in the storyboard. The VoiceOver order is determined by the order of the views in the document outline.

Just drag and drop the views in the view hierarchy in the right order.

Edit:

Sorry I can not post screenhots until 10 reputation. In the storyboard, the document outline is the area on the left where your scenes with their subviews are listed. Here, subviews are ordered one below each other. When you change this order, the reading-order of VoiceOver will change.

Comment: Can you add a screen shot?  I can't see where you mean, thanks.

Comment: [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAccessibilityContainer_Protocol/) say that "order of accessibility elements within the container view should be the same as the order in which the represented elements are presented to the user, from top-left to bottom-right."

From my own testing, voice over by default will do top-left to bottom-right, regardless of the order of the views.

Comment: I’ve only seen the left-to-right, then top-to-bottom, order myself.

Comment: "The VoiceOver order is determined by the order of the views in the document outline" ->  Wrong ( @KenKo's comment is correct )

Comment: @KenKo any documentation for how it determines left to right and top to bottom, if not based on the order of the rendered views ? does it somehow determine it visually ?

Comment: @gaurav5430 I'd be guessing, but I think it would be determined by the position of the elements as they are drawn on the screen. The system will also be locale aware, so for a RTL language, it would go from right to left.

Answer (score 1):

### Swift 5.x

Following [the advice of ChrisJF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34422456/1894067) , I've wrote a little extension to bypass the Apple bug around the correct order reading items.

---

```
extension UIView {
    func setAccessibilityOrder(_ arrayViews:[Any]?){
        self.accessibilityElements = arrayViews
        let arrayStrings:[String] = arrayViews?.map { String(($0 as AnyObject).accessibilityLabel ?? "") } ?? []
        let formatList = arrayStrings.map { _ in "%@" }.joined(separator: ", ")
        self.accessibilityLabel = String(format: formatList, arguments:arrayStrings)
        self.isAccessibilityElement = true
    }
}
```

---

### Usage:

```
view1.accessibilityLabel = "my view 1"
label2.accessibilityLabel = "my label 2"
button3.accessibilityLabel = "my button 3"
let order = [view1, label2, button3]
self.setAccessibilityOrder(order) // or self.view.setAccessibilityOrder(order) if you are on a parent controller
```