# How can you tell the voiceover cursor to jump to a specific element on macOS?

Tags: objective-c, macos, accessibility, voiceover

I've seen a similar question asked for iOS here [Moving Accessibility Voiceover cursor focus to a specific element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20959699/moving-accessibility-voiceover-cursor-focus-to-a-specific-element), but it didn't address my problem as this is a macOs specific issue for me. When I reach a certain element, I want the VO cursor to "jump" to a completely different location. How can I achieve this on mac?

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this? It is probably not what your users will be expecting, unless perhaps you also "jump" back when navigating with VO in the reverse direction. Is hiding the offending UI insufficient for your purposes?

Comment: I concur with Nick K9. Most users will get confused. Depending on what you're doing exactly, there's probably a better way.

Comment: The view hierarchy doesn't place the element intuitively. I have to keep it abstract, but basically, our system handles AX for a custom rendered part of our UI. We wanted to add something to that UI using overlaid native views. The user would expect this element to be at some place in the hierarchy, but it's not because it's not registered in our AX system. Trust me that we're trying to make a change to put it in the right place in the tree, but in the meantime, the expected behavior could also be fixed by "jumping" to the element (and of course jumping back).