# Swift - TableViewCell Accessibility (VoiceOver)

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, accessibility

Hierarchy in my TableViewCell in storyboard is like below:

When I activated voiceover, it reads the labels not in the order in the storyboard but in a mixed order.

```
->TableViewCell
--->Label1
--->Label2
--->Label3
--->Button
--->Label4
```

Is there a way to change the voiceover hierarchy for tableviewcell?

Edit: I tried this in `cellforrowat`, but nothing changed.

```
cell.accessibilityElements = [Label1, Label2, Label3, Button, Label4]
```

Edit 2: Setting  `isAccessibilityElement = false` makes my accessibilityElements order work. But cell selection to voiceover is not working now.

Comment: What have you tried so far? There is a question [similar here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13407513/1305067).

Comment: cell.accessibilityElements = [Label1, Label2, Label3, Button, Label4], but nothing changed

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have simultaneously a parent view *(your table view cell)* and its child views *(label1, button...)* that are [both accessible](http://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios.html#hide-elements-from-accessibility) with VoiceOver: either your cell can be selected or its content.

Instead of selecting each element inside your cell, vocalize the labels when your cell is selected and [add custom actions](http://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios.html#custom-actions) if buttons are available inside.

That's the best way to improve the user experience for your table view cell: one unique selection with possible actions.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55691540/3825084) may help for your implementation.