# VoiceOver is finding a nearby accessible element to read?

Tags: ios, accessibility, voiceover

I'm adding accessibility to my iOS app. I'm seeing a specific situation that when I tap on a UIView that has `isAccessibilityElement = false`, and all of its ancestor views are also `isAccessibilityElement = false`, VoiceOver will speak the text from this view's *sibling* - a different child of this view's parent. And in Accessibility Inspector, when I hover over this view, the sibling lights up.

I don't understand how some view that's not in the hierarchy of the one I'm tapping on could be used for VoiceOver text. I don't see any behavior like this documented for iOS 11. How could this be happening?

*Edit:* I've created a simple project with a UITableView, containing UITableViewCell objects, each of which contains a UILabel. Tapping on a UITableViewCell (outside the UILabel) will read the UILabel within it. How do I disable that behavior, so that only tapping on the label itself, not on its containing UITableViewCell, will read the label?

Comment: @XLE_22 I'm sorry, but it didn't answer the question. I was asking about a situation where _nothing_ in that particular view's hierarchy was an accessible element, and iOS would choose to read something outside the hierarchy. You described a situation where _more than one_ view in a hierarchy is an accessible element and how to get a specific view to be spoken.

Comment: Indeed, I didn't understand your problem at all... you should have told me before. ‍ After reading your edit, I thought you wanted to have only the label of a cell to be vocalized when selected (the cell wouldn't be accessible).  However, your initial situation sounds like a modal view or phantom elements: more information about the structure of your view hierarchy would be welcome if need be. 

Answer (score 1):

A table view cell *(container)* and its content *(children)* cannot be accessible all together *(explanation [here](http://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios.html#hide-elements))*.

Follow the steps hereunder to answer your edit mention so that **only tapping on the label itself**, not on its containing `UITableViewCell`, **will read the label**.

- Create your own `UITableViewCell` class including one label.

  ```
  class TestTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

      @IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!

      override var accessibilityTraits: UIAccessibilityTraits {
          get { return UIAccessibilityTraitNone }
          set {}
      }
  }
  ```
- Define your label as a `UIAccessibilityElement` in the cell implementation to be included in its `accessibilityElements` array.

  ```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                 cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

          let zeCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myPersoCell",
                                                     for: indexPath) as! TestTableViewCell

          zeCell.accessibilityElements = nil

          var elements = [UIAccessibilityElement]()

          let contentA11yElt = UIAccessibilityElement(accessibilityContainer: zeCell)
          contentA11yElt.accessibilityTraits = UIAccessibilityTraitStaticText
          contentA11yElt.accessibilityFrameInContainerSpace = zeCell.contentLabel.frame //To be adapted
          contentA11yElt.accessibilityLabel = "label content"

          elements.append(contentA11yElt)
          zeCell.accessibilityElements = elements

          return zeCell
      }
  ```

Following these code snippets will allow to **select a label located inside a table view cell and to read out its content** as desired.