# ADA - Programmatically shifting VoiceOver focus to another SwiftUI view - compatible with IOS 13+

Tags: ios, swiftui, uikit, accessibility, voiceover

**Overview:**

I'm having difficulty understanding how to properly programmatically shift accessibility focus in a SwiftUI view **compatible with IOS 13+**.

**This means using the newer SwiftUI focus management API available in IOS 15+ is not possible unfortunately.**

Most of the suggestions I've seen are similar to the following post:

*[iOS change accessibility focus.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7529464/ios-change-accessibility-focus)*

where it suggests to change focus by using **UIAccessibility.post(notification: .screenChanged/layoutChanged) argument: View)**

However, my attempts have been unsuccessful.

I have been able to successfully use **UIAccessibility.post(notification: .announcement) argument: String)** in the same way as the code below and it does announce the sting as expected. It takes considerably longer than the asyncAfter timer (Maybe 8 seconds), but it seemed to indicate the post() call is kind of working.

**Code Example:**

A custom expand/collapse with a chevron up or down depending on if it is expanded or collapsed.

I want to programmatically be able to control where focus goes when it is expanded. For instance, I may want to be able to have VoiceOver focus on 'Menu Item 3' in the expanded menu on open.

I was thinking that something close to the code below might work, but I have a lack of understanding of how the argument view in the post is working and not sure if there is a way to use a SwiftUI view or if I need to create a UIKit view and use UIViewRepresentable or wrap it using UIHostingController?

**Current Behavior**

When the menu is expanded, VoiceOver moves to the first item. When the menu is collapsed, the VoiceOver focus shifts to the last text view.

**Desired Behavior**

I would like to be able to definitively decide where VoiceOver focus goes when I expand a menu and be able to more focus to a specific view when a view appears

I've also considered other approaches with the tools available in SwiftUI/IOS 13+. For example, I've played with **accessibility(sortPriority:) and accessibilityElement(children: .combine/.contain/.ignore)** to achieve the desired result, but those efforts have proved unsuccessful as well.

**Code Search:**

The following GitHub search currently produced 10 and 13 results respectively:

https://github.com/search?q=UIAccessibility.post%28notification%3A+.layoutChanged+View+%22import+swiftui%22&type=code

https://github.com/search?q=UIAccessibility.post%28notification%3A+.screenChanged+View+%22import+swiftui%22&type=code

And of those results, the ones used within a SwiftUI view have use an argument of 'nil' (supposedly shifting the focus to the first item on the screen)

This makes me wonder if I'm really off-track.

Any guidance/insight in to how best approach this issue is greatly appreciated!

**SwiftUI View:**

```
struct ExpandingMenu: View {
     @State var expanded: Bool = false

     var body: some View {
         ScrollView {
             VStack(spacing: 12) {
                 Text("Some views above the menu")
                     .accessibility(addTraits: .isStaticText)
                     .accessibility(identifier: "Some view identifier")
                 if self.expanded {
                     VStack(spacing: 12) {
                          Text("Menu Item 1")
                          Text("Menu Item 2")
                          Text("Menu Item 3")
                             .onAppear(perform: {
                                 DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.8) {
                                     UIAccessibility.post(notification: .screenChanged, argument: self)
                            }

                        })
                    Image(systemName: "chevron.up")
                    FullDivider()
                    Spacer()
                }
                .accessibility(addTraits: .isButton)
                .accessibility(identifier: "Menu Expanded")
                .accessibility(removeTraits: .isStaticText)
                .onTapGesture {
                    self.expanded.toggle()
                }
                } else {
                    VStack(spacing: 12) {
                        FullDivider()
                        Image(systemName: "chevron.down")
                        FullDivider()
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    .accessibility(addTraits: .isButton)
                    .accessibility(identifier: "Menu Collapsed")
                    .accessibility(removeTraits: .isStaticText)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        self.expanded.toggle()
                }
            }
            Text("Some views below the menu")
                .accessibility(addTraits: .isStaticText)
                .accessibility(identifier: "Some Text 3")
        }
    }
}
```

**Example collapsed menu:**
[image: Collapsed menu]

**Example expanded menu:**
[image: Expanded menu]

Answer (score 1):

Please try my SwiftUI / UIKit solution to set a focus on accessibility without needing the new focus management API (iOS 15+):

```
import SwiftUI

struct LabelFocusable: View {
    var text: String

    @State private var height: CGFloat = .zero
    
    @Binding var focused: Bool

    var body: some View {
        LabelView(text: text, dynamicHeight: $height, focused: $focused)
            .frame(minHeight: height)
                               .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
    }

    private struct LabelView: UIViewRepresentable {
        var text: String
        
        @Binding var dynamicHeight: CGFloat
        
        @Binding var focused: Bool

        func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UILabel {
            let label = UILabel()
            label.numberOfLines = 0
            label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
            label.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)
            label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 15, weight: .bold)
            label.isAccessibilityElement = true
            label.textAlignment = .center
            return label
        }

        func updateUIView(_ uiView: UILabel, context: Context) {
            uiView.text = text
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                dynamicHeight = uiView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: uiView.bounds.width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)).height
            }
            
            if focused {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    focused = false
                    
                    UIAccessibility.post(notification: UIAccessibility.Notification.layoutChanged, argument: uiView)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Example:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var label1Focused = false
    
    @State private var label2Focused = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 64) {
            Text("Headline")
                .font(.largeTitle)
            
            LabelFocusable(text: "Label 1", focused: $label1Focused)       
            
            LabelFocusable(text: "Label 2", focused: $label2Focused)

            Button {
                label1Focused = true
            } label: {
                Text("Focus Label 1")
            }
            .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
            
            Button {
                label2Focused = true
            } label: {
                Text("Focus Label 2")
            }
            .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
        }
        .padding(.horizontal)
    }
}
```

Comment: what If I have a title, message, and button. And I want to shift focus to the button once the voiceover has read the message. @Peter Kreinz

Comment: @RajaSaad I don't know at the moment. it may need a similar approach for buttons. You can open a new question.